# Unique pair collection

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I want to store two strings in a collection but the combination should be unique eg

```
'1','2'
'2','1'
'1','2' -> not allowed
'2','3'
```

Which collection should I use if I want both strings to be keys?

Comment: Do you mean you want a dictionary or a bidirectional dictionary?

Comment: Is ordering important?

Comment: Ordering is not important but I want to be able to search by first string. I don't care if its bidirectional dictionary as long as combination is unique

Comment: string or character????

Comment: @user2837961 I see now. So the only thing you want unique is combinations. But, above, you have {'1', '2'} and then {'2', '1'}, so the "uniqueness" you're referring to is that you want unique combinations of column A mappings to column B only, but you don't care if the collection has flipped items, like  {'1', '2'} and then {'2', '1'}? You just don't want to have the EXACT same combination, essentially, and that's IT?

Comment: @Alexandru The flipping is allowed since I want column A and Column B to be unique

Comment: @user2837961 Do your strings always contain numbers? Can they be any string whatsoever? There may be simpler approaches than using custom equality comparisons if you can group your key and value into one standard datatype like `string`.

Comment: @Alexandru no the strings can contain anything not just numbers

Comment: @user2837961 Then use McEvoy's solution. It is the simplest and most elegant for your situation, but a little caution: If you had a custom datatype that was not a value type, you would need to manually make it comparable to other datatypes of the same type like some of the other answers have done. Since you are using just strings, you can get away with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `HashSet` of `KeyValuePair<String, String>`.

For example:

```
HashSet<KeyValuePair<String, String>> set = new HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
set.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "2"));
set.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "2"));
```

This will produce only one entry in the set.

For reference:

[KeyValuePair Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[HashSet Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: For that he should use `System.Web`? Then i'd prefer `Tuple<string,string>`.

Comment: Made a mistake in my original answer, should have been System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair

Comment: @Eamonn McEvoy is it possible to search using by the first string in Hashset?

Comment: @user2837961 Yes. Use LINQ: `if (set.Any(x => x.Key == "1"))`. This is the best answer for your situation. Adding `{"1", "2"}` twice will be like adding it only once.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`HashSet<CustomObject>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx), with a custom [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The comparer makes sure that no entries are allowed with duplicate values. I just wrote a sample implementation, adapt it to your convenience.

```
HashSet<CustomObject> x = new HashSet<CustomObject>(new XE());

public class CustomObjectEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<CustomObject>
{
    public bool Equals(CustomObject x, CustomObject y)
    {
        return x.Var1 == y.Var1 && x.Var2 == y.Var2;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        //
    }
}

public class CustomObject
{
    public string Var1 { get; set; }
    public string Var2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Should the properties in CustomObject not be strings?

Comment: Or char. I just saw the integer values so assumed they were all ints.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a custom type and a hashSet collection. For sample:

```
public class Item : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return x.Valie1 == y.Value1 && x.Value2 != y.Value2;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        // implement
    }
}
```

Use a hashSet

```
HashSet<Item> set = new HashSet<Item>();
set.Add(new Item() { Value1 = "1", Value2 = "1" });
```

Answer (score 0):

No duplicates returned

```
   static NameValueCollection GetCollection()
    {
    NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();
    collection.Add("Sam", "Dot Net Perls");
    collection.Add("Bill", "Microsoft");
    collection.Add("Bill", "White House");
    collection.Add("Sam", "IBM");
    return collection;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
    NameValueCollection collection = GetCollection();
    foreach (string key in collection.AllKeys) // <-- No duplicates returned.
    {
        Console.WriteLine(key);
    }
```

duplicates return

```
public class ListWithDuplicates : List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    public void Add(string key, string value)
    {
        var element = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value);
        this.Add(element);
    }
}

var list = new ListWithDuplicates();
list.Add("rr", "11");
list.Add("rr", "22");
list.Add("rr", "33");

foreach(var item in list)
{
    string x = string.format("{0}={1}, ", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Outputs rr=11, rr=22, rr=33.